# dependency injection in lumen

Tags: php, dependency-injection, lumen

I'm trying to understand dependency injection in lumen

I want to add userService

```
{
    protected $userService;
    public function __construct(UserService $userService, $config)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }
```

apply it here:
Console/Commands/Command2.php

```
    $server = app(Server::class, [$config]);
```

getting an error

In Container.php line 993:
  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [  $config ]] in class App\SocketServer\Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies with parameters can be configured in service providers. A service provider can be generated by running:

```
php artisan make:provider UserServiceProvider
```

Modifying the setup method in the `UserServiceProvider.php` file

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(UserService::class, function ($app) {
            $config = ['debug' => true];
            return new UserService($config);
        });
    }
```

registering it in `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers

    App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class,
],
```

And then Laravel will be able to inject the dependency:

```
    protected $userService;
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }
```

Comment: its lumen, friend..
next moment - my UserService  has not __construct function, so i have doubts  UserService($config) is worked fine...

Comment: This also works in lumen  https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers :) @Dimas